# Angular Cli with ASP NET MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, angular, angular-cli

**Do you know how to implement Angular/Cli (Angular 4) with ASP NET MVC.
I made a lot of things and nothing, i can not install it, if you know please help me.**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's difficult to achieve, purely because the `@angular/cli` relies heavily on webpack. It's designed to be much more standalone, at dev time at least. So you have two options available to you: embrace the separation, or integrate webpack dev server into ASP.NET as middleware.

If you take the former option, you'll just start them up separately, and then when you deploy the application - will copy the output html, css and javascript into the `/public` or `/assets` directory of your mvc site. (Typically as a part of your build pipeline.

Alternatively, if you can use aspnet core (which I would recommend), you can use the JavascriptServices package by the core team and they take care of the hard plumbing for you. It's pretty cool, you should check it out:

https://github.com/aspnet/JavaScriptServices
http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2016/05/02/angular2-react-knockout-apps-on-aspnet-core/

Comment: Thanks man. I really appreciate your answer and your time, so I will try to do it with the former way

Comment: Sure, let me see if I can, because I'm new in this xD, but thank you bro you are awesome

Comment: this is not a correct answer... you can totally do this, it just needs a bit of fiddling around... if i get time I'll post the answer as I have done this

Comment: I look forward to seeing it. :) If you reread what I said, I made it very clear that it was difficult to achieve - not that that it was impossible.

Comment: @EfrainPerez Have you managed to get it working? I would really like to know because I have the same problem

Comment: @Lobato hi, i recommend that you use asp net as a web service, and I use angular and nodejs to connect with the web service in asp net. I hope that this is useful to you. Please let me know If i wasn't clear with the answer and thanks for the comment

Comment: Can you point me into the right direction? I have a separate Angular CLI module and a ASP MVC module which has to be deployed in Azure. I am having a hard time since both want to handle their own deployment